# Installating the "bezier" package with pip3 fails

Tags: python, pip

```
pip3 install bezier                                   
Collecting bezier
  Using cached bezier-2021.2.12.tar.gz (313 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      The BEZIER_INSTALL_PREFIX environment variable must be set.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I am trying to install [*bezier*](https://pypi.org/project/bezier/) but there is a error in installing with *pip*.

Comment: The error message clearly says: "*The BEZIER_INSTALL_PREFIX environment variable must be set.*" Have you tried that? What have you tried? What does the documentation say? What is your question? What do you need help with? What is your Python version, your *pip* version, your operating system?

Comment: Also note that this question is not about bezier curves, but about installing a Python package. Don't add a tag that "has the right name", make sure to read the tag's description. See the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [setup.py](https://github.com/dhermes/bezier/blob/de7365258ed693539891e90906a763acf01195a6/setup.py#L154) file of the bezier package, the `BEZIER_INSTALL_PREFIX` environment variable presence is checked. Set it to either `True` or `False` before installing the package, like this:

```bash
BEZIER_INSTALL_PREFIX=true pip install bezier
# or
BEZIER_INSTALL_PREFIX=false pip install bezier
```

---

Moreover, as stated inside the [README.md](https://pypi.org/project/bezier/) of the package:

> To install a pure Python version (i.e. with no binary extension):
>
> ```
> $ BEZIER_NO_EXTENSION=true \
> >   python   -m pip install --upgrade bezier --no-binary=bezier
> ```

This `BEZIER_NO_EXTENSION` environment variable is checked before `BEZIER_INSTALL_PREFIX`. See the [setup.py](https://github.com/dhermes/bezier/blob/de7365258ed693539891e90906a763acf01195a6/setup.py#L150). Setting it will avoid checking the presence of `BEZIER_INSTALL_PREFIX`.